# Error using word_tokenize UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, tokenize

I am new to nltk. I was trying some codes.
i know so many are asked this type of questions still i don't understand.
i also tried nltk.download('all')
except panlex.lite package everything is up-to date.

Here is my code,

```
short_pos = open("sr/positive.txt","r").read()
short_neg = open("sr/negative.txt","r").read()

documents = []
for r in short_pos.split('\n'):
    documents.append( (r, "pos") )

for r in short_neg.split('\n'):
    documents.append( (r, "neg") )

all_words = []
short_pos_words = word_tokenize(short_pos)
short_neg_words = word_tokenize(short_neg)
```

It gives me this following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:/7th sem/minor_project/hotel_recommended/testing/sentiment_mod.py", line 52, in <module>
    short_pos_words = word_tokenize(short_pos)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 106, in word_tokenize
    return [token for sent in sent_tokenize(text, language)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 91, in sent_tokenize
    return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1226, in tokenize
    return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1274, in sentences_from_text
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1265, in span_tokenize
    return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1304, in _realign_boundaries
    for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 311, in _pair_iter
    for el in it:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1280, in _slices_from_text
    if self.text_contains_sentbreak(context):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1325, in text_contains_sentbreak
    for t in self._annotate_tokens(self._tokenize_words(text)):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1460, in _annotate_second_pass
    for t1, t2 in _pair_iter(tokens):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 310, in _pair_iter
    prev = next(it)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 577, in _annotate_first_pass
    for aug_tok in tokens:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 542, in _tokenize_words
    for line in plaintext.split('\n'):
```

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You dont need o give the whole error. the last line is enough.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @WhiteShadow and i will do it in next time

Comment: Try `import io;  io.open("sr/negative.txt","r", encoding='utf8')` instead of `open("sr/negative.txt","r")`

Comment: i got this error message while trying to run using your (@alvas) suggestion

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:\7th sem\minor_project\hotel_recommended\testing\sentiment_mod.py", line 49, in <module>
    short_pos = io.open("sr/positive.txt", encoding='utf8').read()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\codecs.py", line 302, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 4645: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Use the same `io.open` for positive... -_- |||